# How to run ant inside java command

Tags: selenium, ant, junit

I have written a Selenium Junit test case (say a1.java). There is another java program say a2.java which reads a spreadsheet for different config related values and it sets these values into member variables of a1.java. So a2.java runs main program a1.java many times. To get the test report, I have created ant build file (build.xml).

Is there some way to write some java code to execute my build file? Note I am using Ant version (1.8.3.v20120321-1730) for this purpose.

I saw somewhere to use org.apache.tools.ant.Project but its not working. Any help in this regard please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the simplest solution is to call `org.apache.tools.ant.Main#main` just like the ant command line does.

For instance:

```
Main.main(new String[] { "-f", "path/to/the/build.xml"});
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate it by some example?

Comment: Edited my answer with an exemple.